# Find specific value while scraping and ignore when value is not found

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, find

So, I'm creating a web scraping tool and I would like to implement an IF statement that checks if the text 'Comarca de' is inside an paragraph in the HTML, but it's not working, here's what I've tried:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pagina_scrap = str('http://www8.tjmg.jus.br/juridico/diario/index.jsp?dia=0903&completa=interior|0720')
pagina_open = urllib.request.urlopen(pagina_scrap)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pagina_open, 'html.parser')
arquivo = open("INTERIOR0903.txt", "w+")

if soup.find('p', text='Comarca de'):
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='corpo'):
        print(div.text)
        arquivo.write(div.text)
```

Without the IF statement the scraping works fine, but with the with statement nothing happens, and this link is one that should get the text.

Comment: Apparently `soup.find('p', text='Comarca de')` always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get text of the p tag

```
 print(soup.find('p').get_text())
```

you will get output from the url you have mentioned above like

## » Consultas » Diário do Judiciário

obviously  this will return False `soup.find('p', text='Comarca de'):`
so it wont execute further after the if statement

Comment: I get it, maybe I have to find another way to solve this :)

Comment: Yes ,you need to find  different way .

Answer (score 0):

So, I was looking only at the Soup while python offered me the native find function.
In the end it worked like that:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    dia_hoje = input("Qual a data? DDMM")
    #num_jornal = input("Qual o número do Jornal?")
    pagina_scrap = str('http://www8.tjmg.jus.br/juridico/diario/index.jsp?dia=' + dia_hoje + '&completa=interior|0720')
    pagina_open = urllib.request.urlopen(pagina_scrap)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pagina_open, 'html.parser')
    arquivo = open("INTERIOR0903.txt", "a")
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='corpo'):
        if str(div.text).find('COMARCA DE'):
            arquivo.write(div.text)
        else:
            print("Didn't worked")
```